# Delphi 10.1 How extract a JSON value into multiple categories

Tags: json, delphi

I have extracted the UK Gov [Bank Holidays](https://www.api.gov.uk/gds/bank-holidays/#bank-holidays) using Delphi 10.1 with `TRESTClient` and `TRESTRequest`.

This is the results (cut down version):

```json
{ "england-and-wales": {"division":"england-and-wales","events": [{"title":"New Year’s Day","date":"2018-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"Good Friday","date":"2018-03-30","notes":"","bunting":false}, {"title":"Christmas Day","date":"2025-12-25","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"Boxing Day","date":"2025-12-26","notes":"","bunting":true}]},
    
"scotland": {"division":"scotland","events": [{"title":"New Year’s Day","date":"2018-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"2nd January","date":"2018-01-02","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"Christmas Day","date":"2025-12-25","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"Boxing Day","date":"2025-12-26","notes":"","bunting":true}]},
    
"northern-ireland": {"division":"northern-ireland","events": [{"title":"New Year’s Day","date":"2018-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"St Patrick’s Day","date":"2018-03-19","notes":"Substitute day","bunting":true}, {"title":"Christmas Day","date":"2025-12-25","notes":"","bunting":true}, {"title":"Boxing Day","date":"2025-12-26","notes":"","bunting":true}]} }
```

Can anyone give an example how to iterate through the `JSONValue` and display the contents to look something like:

```
england-and-wales
title=New Year’s Day, date=2018-01-01,notes=,bunting=true
title=Good Friday, date=2018-03-30,notes=,bunting=true
title=Christmas Day, date=2025-12-25,notes=,bunting=true
title=Boxing Day, date=2025-12-26,notes=,bunting=true
    
scotland
title=New Year’s Day, date=2018-01-01,notes=,bunting=true
title=2nd January, date=2018-01-02,notes=,bunting=true
title=Christmas Day, date=2025-12-25,notes=,bunting=true
title=Boxing Day, date=2025-12-26,notes=,bunting=true
    
northern-ireland
title=New Year’s Day, date=2018-01-01,notes=,bunting=true
title=St Patrick’s Day, date=2018-03-19,notes=,bunting=true
title=Christmas Day, date=2025-12-25,notes=,bunting=true
title=Boxing Day, date=2025-12-26,notes=,bunting=true
```

I would like to iterate through each division (country) and display the division name, then iterate through the events and display the Title, date, notes and bunting.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` will be a `TJSONValue` that points at a [`TJSONObject`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject) instance.

Cast that instance to `TJSONObject`, and then you can iterate through its [`Pairs[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Pairs) property, or use a [`for..in` loop](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements) on the `TJSONObject` itself.

For each pair, its `JsonString` will be the country/division name, and its `JsonValue` will be a `TJSONValue` that points to a `TJSONObject` instance.

Cast each instance to `TJSONObject` and use its [`Values[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Values) property to access the `division` and `events` elements.

Each `events`' value will be a `TJSONValue` that points to a [`TJSONArray`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray) instance.  Cast the instance to `TJSONArray` and then you can iterate its [`Items[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray.Items) property, or use a `for..in` loop on the `TJSONArray` itself.

For each item in the array, cast it to `TJSONObject` and iterate its `Pairs[]` or use its `Values[]` to access the `title`, `date`, etc elements.

So, for example:

```pascal
var
  responseObj, divisionObj, eventObj: TJSONObject;
  divisionPair, eventPair: TJSONPair;
  eventsArr: TJSONArray;
  eventItem: TJSONValue;
  list: TStringList;
  tempStr: string;
begin
  ...
  list := TStringList.Create;
  try
    responseObj := RESTResponse1.JsonValue as TJSONObject;
    for divisionPair in responseObj do
    begin
      divisionObj := divisionPair.JsonValue as TJSONObject;
      if (list.Count > 0) then list.Add('');
      list.Add(divisionObj.Values['division'].Value);
      eventsArr := divisionObj.Values['events'] as TJSONArray;
      for eventItem in eventsArr do
      begin
        eventObj := eventItem as TJSONObject;
        tempStr := '';
        for eventPair in eventObj do
        begin
          if (tempStr <> '') then tempStr := tempStr + ', ';
          tempStr := tempStr + eventPair.JsonString.Value + '=' + eventPair.JsonValue.Value;
        end;
        list.Add(tempStr);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    // use list as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy. Very precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **JSONToDelphiClass** tool, which allows you to generate the necessary classes to read the JSON data in a simple way, from a JSON.

https://jsontodelphi.com/

Using this tool and the generated classes the code is greatly simplified.

You can do something like this:

```
uses
  BaseClass;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Parse the JSON (in Memo1)
  var root: TRoot := TRoot.Create;
  root.AsJson := Memo1.Lines.Text;

  for var i:integer := 0 to (root.EnglandAndWales.Events.Count - 1) do
    memo2.Lines.Add('Title=' + root.EnglandAndWales.Events[i].Title + ' ' +
                    'Date=' + DateToStr(root.EnglandAndWales.Events[i].Date) + ' ' +
                    'Notes=' + root.EnglandAndWales.Events[i].Notes);
end;
```

To get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you German. I'm impressed with the way https://jsontodelphi.com/ creates a class unit based on the JSON.